# checkbox value log "ON" instead of true or false

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write my own code but when I console.log the in updateJSON() it gives me "on"

I don't know why it says on. I checked the event.target and it is a checkbox but why the console logs "on"

here is my code

```
        let task = {
            "list": {
                "clean the garden" : true,
                "clean the fence": true,
                "clean the room": false
            }
        }
        const div = document.getElementById("output");
        for(let key in task.list){
            //console.log(key);
            var status = !task.list[key] ? 'checked': 'unchecked'
            div.innerHTML += `
            <li>${key}
            <input type='checkbox' ${status}>
            </li>
            `
        }
        const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('#output input[type="checkbox"]');
        for(let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length;i++){
            checkboxes[i].onchange = updateJSON;
        }
        function updateJSON(){
            var key = event.target.value;
            console.log(key);
        }
```

Not sure I understand. input type of checkbox doesn't have value but has checked or unchecked which is true or false and one is checked when I click it, it still logs on. if it is ON and OFF kind of thing, why doesn't it log OFF

Comment: _"input type of checkbox doesn't have value"_ - [That's not true](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#Value)

Comment: _"but has checked or unchecked which is true or false"_ - No, it has a [`checked` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox) which is either `true` or `false`.

Comment: And that the _value_, if none was actually explicitly specfied, defaults to `On`, is also explained there on that MDN page.

Comment: @Andreas thanks for the clarity, can you explain in your answer why it is ON and why not OFF?

Comment: [`default/on`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#dom-input-value-default-on): _"On getting, if the element has a `value` content attribute, return that attribute's value; otherwise, return the string `"on"`"_

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checkbox always On](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25897406/checkbox-always-on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look into this:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('chk1').value);
console.log(document.getElementById('chk2').value);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="chk1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="chk2" value="10" />
```

As you are using `event.target.value` here and checkbox doesn't have a default value so you have to provide the value otherwise it will be `on`.